# Is that an easy way to resolve this blank ("") and "null" issue between MVC EF2.0 and EF4.6?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have converted an ASP.net MVC application from EF 2.0 to EF 4.6. Most of functions are working well, but  except the issue with the empty data binding.

It seems the two framework generate different result with the field data fields without any user input data,

When submit a razor view with some user input data to controller, the data field without any user input, in EF2.0 it returns blank (""), but in EF4.6, it returns `null`.

this causes big problem, since I do have some codes without any condition checking, and it runs OK in EF2.0, but it generates run-time error in EF 4.6.

For example: this code:

```
VideoRequest.ConfStartDates = RequestModel.SetConferenceDates(viewModel.ConfAdditionalDates);
```

the `ConfAdditionalDates` field doesnot contain any user input data, so in EF2.0, `viewModel.ConfAdditionalDates = ""`, but in EF4.6, `viewModel.ConfAdditionalDates = null`. so for the function call

```
VideoRequest.ConfStartDates = RequestModel.SetConferenceDates(viewModel.ConfAdditionalDates);

// this will be working OK for EF2.0, 
// but it will generate run-time in EF4.6. 
public DateTime[] SetConferenceDates(string repeatingDateList)  
{ 
    // here is the run-time error happened for EF4.6
    // but it is OK for EF2.0 as 
    if (repeatingDateList.Length > 0)  
    {
```

I can add an IF condition to check all UI fields with null value and make something like:

```
if (viewModel.ConfAdditionalDates == null) 
{
    viewModel.ConfAdditionalDates = "";
}
```

But if I am doing this way, I have to check all source codes of controller and make sure all fields with null in EF4.6 to add this if condition to convert it to blank (""), that will be a lot for work.

So my question is that : is there an easy way to do a change in config file (web config file) or property file set up, so all empty UI fields will be generated to blankd ("") in controller side in stead of `null` ?

Thanks a lot for any input.

Comment: Format code by indenting with four spaces or highlighting it and pressing the `{}` button.

Comment: How is your EF4 data context set up? EDMX File? If yes, you can set Default Values for every Column in the EDMX Model viewer...

Comment: Personally, I think that if the content can be null (as opposed to empty string), you should handle the nulls. I get that's not what you want to do. To do this, you can make use of the null conditional / null coallescing operators. Eg VideoRequest.ConfStartDates = RequestModel.SetConferenceDates(viewModel.ConfAdditionalDates?? string.Empty);. And if items *shouldn't* be nulls, change the underlying properties to not be nullable